# Prepopulating record id from parent object on command link button on a record new page in visual force

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirement where I have a add new command link button. On clicking the button, I want to redirect the user to a record new page with a record id prepopulated. How do I pass parameter from a command link button on visual force to a record new page where I have an extension controller where I can prepopulate the parent record id?
Buyan

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Please add those details by editing and adding them to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL hacking if you use visualforce. I did a similar requirement a while ago, but I was redirecting from an apex class instead of a button, but the logic would be the same.

You only need to add a couple parameters into your url: the field id with the record name and field id appended by `_lkid` with record id.

Apex example:

```
PageReference p = new PageReference('/' + Lead.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/e');
Map<String, String> m = p.getParameters();
Account myAcc = [SELECT Id, Name 
                    FROM Account 
                    LIMIT 1];
m.putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());
m.remove('save_new');
m.put('CF00Nw0000008UVpZ', myAcc.Name);
m.put('CF00Nw0000008UVpZ_lkid', myAcc.Id);
m.put('nooverride', '1');
return p;
```

In order to find the field id, go to the record creation page, right click on the field and select **Inspect Element**. You will then see something like:

```
<input id="CF00N1x000002PKHA" maxlength="255" name="CF00N1x000002PKHA" onchange="getElementByIdCS('CF00N1x000002PKHA_lkid').value='';getElementByIdCS('CF00N1x000002PKHA_mod').value='1';" size="20" tabindex="4" type="text">
```

Use this id in your button and you should be good to go.